# Can't connect to MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have an issue with my MySQL container, i can't connect to container.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
apache:
build: ./
ports:
    - 1814:80
volumes:
    - ./code:/app
links:
    - db
environment:
    - APACHE_SERVER_NAME=local.dev
    - PHP_SHORT_OPEN_TAG=On
    - PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=E_ALL
    - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=On
    - PHP_HTML_ERRORS=On

db:
image: mysql:5.6
ports:
    - "3333:3306"
volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    MYSQL_DATABASE: app
```

I run with `docker-compose up -d --build`.

After that, i use `docker ps` to see running container

https://i.imgsafe.org/3caf28c5f0.png

Then i use `docker exec -it mddev_apache_1 /bin/bash` to running an interactive shell in `mddev_apache_1` container.

But when i trying to connect to MySQL, its refused.

https://i.imgsafe.org/3ccfde1f73.png

Any idea why i can't connect to MySQL container ?

Thanks.

==================================================

## UPDATE

I change my `docker-compose.yml` to :

```
version: '2'

services:
apache:
    build: ./
    container_name: web-server
    ports:
        - 1814:80
    volumes:
        - ./code:/app
    links:
        - db
    environment:
        - APACHE_SERVER_NAME=local.dev
        - PHP_SHORT_OPEN_TAG=On
        - PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=E_ALL
        - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=On
        - PHP_HTML_ERRORS=On
    networks:
        report:
            aliases:
                - web-server
db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: database
    ports:
        - "3333:3306"
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
        MYSQL_DATABASE: app
    networks:
        report:
            aliases:
                - database

networks:
report:
    driver: bridge
```

But i still can't connect to my MySQL container.

`http://i.imgsafe.org/4eb89f3857.png`

I try to inspect my networks and my container.

`mddev_report` network inspect : `http://i.imgsafe.org/4eae17a27f.png`

`web-server` container inspect : `http://i.imgsafe.org/4ec74e5d52.png`

`database` container inspect : `http://i.imgsafe.org/4ecb129d2d.png`

Comment: What version compose are you using? Are you using any networks other than `default`?

Comment: `docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7`. No, i dont use any networks.

Comment: Sorry, ment on the compose.yml file, (`version: 'x'`) hehe.

Comment: Oh, i dont use `version` parameter at compose.yml. It is mandatory to use `version` ?

Comment: Well, if your containers starts I guess it isn't. Not sure what it defaults to though!
Do a inspect on the mddev_default network and your containers (`docker inspect mddev_default` and `docker inspect mddev_apache_1`, `docker inspect mddev_db_1`) and make sure that both your containers are on the same network (`default`) and got the aliases you expect them to have.

Comment: @Jite i just do some update with my `docker-compose.yml` at my question above. can you check that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mysql container exposes port **3306** to its network while it mapps its port 3306 to hosts 3333 port.
When you use the `ports` property you mapp the port to the localhost, not the other containers on the network.

From inside the `web-server`container you should be able to connect to the mysql server via `mysql -uroot -padmin -h database -P 3306` while from your host you should be able to use `mysql -uroot -padmin -h localhost -P 3333`.

Answer (score 0):

you are linking your docker to db...I think db is not valid or has changed its IP...so you need to stop your mysql docker, commit it and rm it then trying to run the new image again.

if it fails instead of running it in detached mode (-d) you can run it in interactive mode (-it) to see if and exception occurs when running it.

Comment: i just do some update with my `docker-compose.yml` at my question above. can you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue, approved answer didn't work for me.
What worked was pruning the docker containers

`docker system prune -a` *This will clear all the data associated with the unused containers*

After this I run `docker compose up --build` and was able to connect to mysql container without any issues (using 127.0.0.1 as a host and 3333 as a port)
I have slightly different `.yml` file tho.

Additional information about [prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#options)